# Access full path from JFilechooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I want a path of "Turbo C++" folder when I click on approve but whenever i approves it gives me path of "c:" because Turbo C++ folder is in "C:". How to get full path of folder.

[JFilechooser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFNyf.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589386/how-to-save-file-using-jfilechooser-in-java see this link

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

You Must be select File From JFileChooser. They doen't visible if you select Directoy only [JFileChooser Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile())
Sets the selected file. If the file's parent directory is not the current directory, changes the current directory to be the file's parent directory.
          using a getAbsolutePath shows path of Folder.

```
    File selectedFile=JFileChooser_object.getSelectedFile();
    System.out.println("selected File path"+selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());



      public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
      if (jButton.isEnabled())
      {
      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
      chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
      chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
      File selectedPfile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
      jTextField1.setText(selectedPfile.getAbsolutePath());
     }
    }
```

Comment: but i don't  want to access any file instead I have to save a file and that's why i need current Directory not selected file's path.